# When is ELFCLASSNONE used in an ELF file?

Tags: elf

I am learning about ELF. The file class can be one of `ELFCLASS32`, `ELFCLASS64` or `ELFCLASSNONE`.

However, I cannot find any example usage of `ELFCLASSNONE`.

What is it used for ? And when ? Is it actually used anywhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it actually used anywhere ?

No.

(It's only used to detect invalid ELF files.)

> Used where?

Anywhere validity of the ELF file is verified. Here is an [example](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.12.4/source/tools/perf/util/symbol-elf.c#L1262) from the Linux kernel tools.

> even there, ELFCLASSNONE is not used.

You *don't know* what parts of the ELF header `readelf` examined before it concluded that `.bashrc` is not an ELF file. It may have looked at `ei_ident[EI_CLASS]` and compared the value with `ELFCLASSNONE` (though likely it didn't).

If you make a copy of e.g. `/bin/date`, and write a 0 byte into 5th byte of the copy (`EI_IDENT == 4`) to corrupt it, then run `readelf -h` on that copy, you'll probably get an "invalid ELF class" or similar message.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Used where ? If I try using it on an invalid ELF file, like `readelf -h .bashrc`, I get `readelf: Error: Not an ELF file`, seems like even there, `ELFCLASSNONE` is not used.